# Question about memory process and function sharing

Tags: c, assembly, ram

1)Why cant we use virtual address in c instead variable for example instead writing int x ; we may create a pointer to the first address in the stack like that int *x=1; ,and if we liked to declare second variable .
we used the next address like that int *y=2.
or we can use the last address valued in the stack as dynamic array instead of using the heap.

2)
Does function share the same stack and if they do why can't we access local variable of function out side the function.
i think they don't but I cant see how the function context changed because they don't rum at the same time

3)
Does the long type takes two address in the stack that each one of them is 4 bytes?

If it does isn't it change the math operators

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. Why cant we use virtual address in c instead variable for example instead writing int x ; we may create a pointer to the first address in the stack like that int *x=1; ,and if we liked to declare second variable . we used the next address like that int *y=2. or we can use the last address valued in the stack as dynamic array instead of using the heap.

Well, you can use virtual addresses instead a variable, like `int* a=(int*)0x8000B`, this will only work in environments without OS, like in Bootloaders, as the address, a program is loaded is often different, if you use an OS.

You could do `int* x=(int*)1`, `int* x=(int*)5`, but it may crash on some architectures, as these are not aligned to a multiple of `sizeof(int)`(Normally 2 or 4 bytes).
Furthermore, it will only work with such addresses, if you write a program without an OS, as most OS reserve the first few pages. ==> You can't do anything with them.

> we can use the last address valued in the stack as dynamic array instead of using the heap.

Sorry, I really don't understand what you mean. The stack is no dynamic array, it's just a memory address and some free space (Like 2MB on "normal" PCs or only a few hundred bytes in embedded devices).

> 2. Does function share the same stack and if they do why can't we access local variable of function out side the function. i think they don't but I cant see how the function context changed because they don't rum at the same time

Yes, they share the same stack.
You could access them with some tricks, but these are quite evil.
Suppose you have a function `_start`. It starts with an empty stack (rbp=0x1000,rsp=0x1000). Then some local variables are allocated on the stack. (rbp=0x1000,rsp=0xff0). After that, it calls `main`.
The address to jump to is stored on the stack and the base pointer is updated.
Now the stack pointer and stack base pointer have these addresses: rbp=0xfe8,rsp=0xfe8
Because the SysV-ABI mandates a 16-byte alignment, you have to subtract again 8 bytes.
rbp=0xfe8,rsp=0xfe0.
Now you could access some local variable from start using `movq 22(%rsp),%rax`. You may have now either a part of a local or a whole local.
This trick can fail with every minor change of the source code or compiler flags.

> 3. Does the long type takes two address in the stack that each one of them is 4 bytes?

No, a long type takes `sizeof(long)` bytes on the stack. An address has a fixed size. Either four (32-bit systems) or eight (64-bit systems).

Comment: "some embedded devices may only have two bytes" Actually they may not, `long` is guaranteed to be at least 4 bytes large, since `LONG_MAX` must at least be the value `+2147483647` or larger and `LONG_MIN` must at least be `-2147483647` or smaller. This is guaranteed by the C standard (5.2.4.2.1).

Comment: I referenced the address, not the long. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Ok well that's quite a topic of it's own, since it is common for embedded systems to use extended memory with bank/page handling.

Comment: @JCWasmx86, the first part of the question seems to ask about loading fixed addresses into pointers. Indeed, there was a long time that this was actually done. Compilers could determine many (non-stack variable) addresses at compile-time, and pointers would be crafted with fixed values. This changed with ASLR and position-independent-code, which is the norm for most cases now. This allows code to be laid out at random locations in the virtual address space, and global variables are stored at fixed offsets to the code.

Comment: Secondly, @dase haish, local variables are only a C-language construct. It is indeed possible to access values outside the current stack frame, and is a common exploit in buffer-overflow attacks. Since all values are stored in the same virtual-memory space, the only challenge is crafting a pointer to other functions' stack frames, and this is simple enough with array accesses in which you can control the index. The machine language does not prevent it. C makes the choice to restrict what the machine code allows, for the sake of ease of programmability.

Answer (score 2):

> for example instead writing int x ; we may create a pointer to the first address in the stack

Because C is more high level than assembler. The C language doesn't know or care about the existence of a stack. One of the main benefits with higher level languages compared to assembler is to get rid of manual stack management. Because one of the most common bugs in assembler is forgetting to push/pop something on the stack - you never get bugs like that in C, since the instructions for handling the stack are generated by the compiler.

So a C programmer does not want to manually handle the stack, mainly because it's a pain to do so. The pseudo code you describe is rather close to how assembler works, where instructions often work in relation to the stack pointer. "Read memory location SP+3" etc.

> or we can use the last address valued in the stack as dynamic array instead of using the heap

No, because the stack has a limited size and is also used for storing registers and return addresses as part of the ABI calling convention. The heap is a higher layer concept where large chunks of data can be stored and shared with everything inside the same process, or with other processes even, depending on system.

It's a common problem that programming teachers simplify things to much and say that there are two forms of memory: the stack and the heap. And then students get obsessed with those two and start making all kinds of wild conclusions. In reality a mainstream computer got `.stack`, `.data`, `.bss`, `.heap`, `.rodata`, `.text` and various other segments (often different flavours of the mentioned ones). Variables may be stored in any of these segments. For example they end up mixed with the program code inside `.text` in case they are optimized into register access instead of stored on the stack.

> Does function share the same stack

If you mean if local variables inside different functions share the same stack, then yes they do in the normal case, assuming single-thread, single-process.

> Does the long type takes two address in the stack that each one of them is 4 bytes?

The size of `long` isn't specified by the standard and it could be 4 or 8 bytes large. Where they are allocated depends on the context.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Why cant we use virtual address in c instead variable for example instead writing int x ; we may create a pointer to the first address in the stack like that int *x=1; ,and if we liked to declare second variable . we used the next address like that int *y=2. or we can use the last address valued in the stack as dynamic array instead of using the heap.

In C, if you want stack storage you either declare local variables or allocate stack memory using `alloca`.  For example, we could do:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    typedef struct {
        int x;
        int y;
    } myStruct;

    myStruct *p = (myStruct *) alloca ( sizeof myStruct );

    p -> x = 100;
    p -> y = 200;
    p -> x += 100;
}
```

This give us storage `x` & `y` that we can refer to via `p->x` and `p->y`.

However, using local variables is much simpler, and requires the compiler to do less work to figure out that the local variables might not even need stack storage, they could simply live in CPU registers.

> 2. Does function share the same stack and if they do why can't we access local variable of function out side the function. i think they don't but I cant see how the function context changed because they don't rum at the same time

For each thread, there is a dynamic call chain, for which all functions in the thread are sharing the same stack for local variables.  More specifically, a function invocation conceptually activates a frame or record in the stack.

There are indeed languages that allow non-local references — references outside their own locals but that are not globals.  Such languages generally support functions nested within functions.  Especially with first class function (function pointers) these are often called closures.  In older languages like Pascal, the use of non-local variables offered a poor person's object oriented programming capability.  Supporting any of these requires considerable machinery under the covers, frame pointers and back links, etc..  The C programming language chose not to implement nested functions I believe for simplification purposes.  It can be substituted for by using heap objects, which are more general purpose (but require manual allocation and releasing).

> 3. Does the long type takes two address in the stack that each one of them is 4 bytes?

Potentially, yes.